# How to break login loop on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I changed the settings on ubuntu 14.04 so that I could log in without password. Surprize, surprize, when I restarted I couldn't log in anymore. It shows me a window with my username and a button "log in" ( misses the text area for password ), but when I push de button it doesn't succeed to start... It's a kind of login loop and I have no idea how to escape from that, I'm helpless even in recovery mode. Please, help!
The originality of my question: the fact that Ubuntu blocked imediately after I changed the access settings, eliminating the password step. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, this usually happens when the Desktop Environment cannot be started, since the login manager comes up when the DE quits. Try resetting your Unity settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I tried this and it didn't work! Actually it didn't work anything! The only solution that I found was to reinstall Ubuntu, but the biggest problem was the information on the hard disk.So I created another Ubuntu .iso image ( I preferred Ubuntu Studio because it downloaded quickly ) and firstly I worked on my computer in live session. I had to delete “/” ( root ) and “swap” partitions, then I restarted de computer and installed Ubuntu Studio in the free space created. From Ubuntu Studio I could see the “/home” partition of the old Ubuntu, but I found it encrypted(so unaccessible!).

Comment: To make it accessible I opened the terminal and I put there “sudo ecryptfs-recover-private”. After typing my password showed succesively:
“INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories ( this might take a while )...”
“INFO: Found [ the name of the encrypted directory ]”
“Try to recover this directory?[y/N]”
“INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase

Comment: Do you know your LOGIN passphrase?[y/N]”
“INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...”
Here I had to introduce the password of the OLD Ubuntu and I got the message:
“INFO: Success! Private data mounted at [/tmp/...]” and gave me the address where were saved all my documents.
Lesson learned! I will never have just one Ubuntu partition! In this moment my machine rules Ubuntu Studio and Voyager.